# Best way to mount stuff on 5/8" thick shiplap board wall?

Tags: walls, screws, hanging, anchor, fastener

We have a shiplap accent wall (5/8" thick pine boards) where we need to mount some wall coat hangers and other stuff that will be relatively heavy. Should we just mount items with screws or use plastic or metal anchors?

If we use just screws, is it preferred to use screws that won't poke out the back (the wall has no wiring or plumbing) or can we use screws longer than 5/8"? I can't find any references online about strength issues (or positives) of screws that extend beyond the wood and poke out the other side.

Comment: picture would help

Comment: the correct way to hang "other stuff that will be relatively heavy" is to either screw into studs or install blocking between studs and screw into blocking. 5/8 inch timber is not designed for heavy capacity

Comment: How heavy will the hangers need to hold?  There's no benefit to part of the fastener extending behind the board, unless it's so long that it penetrates a stud or another structural member behind.  Pine is a relatively soft wood, so...

Comment: Responding to all comments: The items to hang aren't super heavy, it's like coats, keys, mail, shoes, etc. The framing isn't accessible and we are not removing and reinstalling the shiplap to add blocking. Anyway, I asked elsewhere and the suggestion was to use toggle anchors, much like one would in a lath and plaster wall.

Comment: As long as your hooks have a base big enough to cover the size of the hole a toggle needs, that'll be OK.